# Browser based audio capture, then post to server side

Tags: html, flash, audio-recording, audio-capture

Working on a project that will need browser / device cross compatible audio recording (video is not required, but may utilise camera audio inputs). Thinking some kind of HTML5 and flash fallback (for idevices / IE / old browsers etc).

The HTML5 demos I have found dont seem to work. Can confirm my mic works in my OS
http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html (doesnt seem to pickup audio, however saving file works but it just plays no sound)
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/ (wont even prompt me for access to mic)

Also I have found a nice flash example here (http://www.jordansthings.com/blog/?p=5) but I am not a flash dev.

Wondered if there was some kind of API / library with fallbacks, that also allowed not only capture, but posting this to a server side script for further processing. Eg user presses a button, starts speaking, presses stop, then sends that file to the server rather than daving the file to client.

So my question(s):

- Is there an audio capture API / library that would handle all of this for me including fallbacks
- Is it possible to send the captured audio to the server without clunky save + upload
- Does anyone have some nice working examples of either html5 or flash?

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to create your own solution using the following:

https://code.google.com/p/wami-recorder/

It's a flash recorder with an javascript interface.

Check SO for examples, alternatives etc:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=https%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fp%2Fwami-recorder%2F